# how to permanently set environment variable for boot2docker

Tags: linux, shell, docker, boot2docker

I have tried to put my environment variable at /var/lib/boot2docker/profile file at guest machine, and restart it

> export http_proxy=http://proxy:port

then i open shell from my host machine (Windows 7) by using

> docker-machine ssh default

I can't find 'http_proxy' from my environment variable by using

> env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker` daemon sources `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` before starting. The `HTTP_PROXY` variable will be available in the `docker` daemons environment. Users logging in via `ssh` will *not* see this variable.

Any `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files will be loaded into a users profile at login but as you pointed out, this is reset back to the base image after every reboot.

The `/var/lib/boot2docker/` directory contains the files that are persisted over reboots.  [The `bootlocal.sh` will be run at the end of startup. `bootsync.sh` file will be run before docker.](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)

Edit `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh` to include

```
echo 'export HTTP_PROXY="http://whatever"' > /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

Then the variable will be available for anything that logs in after `docker` has started for the first time.

```
○ → docker-machine restart default-docker
...
○ → docker-machine ssh default-docker
...
docker@default-docker:~$ echo $HTTP_PROXY
http://whatever
```

Comment: this only serve temporary, after i restart docker machine it will revert back. I need to have environment variable persist after restart.

Comment: Since `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` is for setting environment variables, `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh` would be a more appropriate place to add that bit of scripting. (see https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)

Answer (score 1):

When [PHPdocker.io](http://phpdocker.io) generates a docker-compose.yml file, it also puts in a section for the environment variables.

```
tie-mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: tie-mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name
    - MYSQL_USER=db_user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_password
```

It starts running Docker-compose from the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", 
      inline: "cd /home/docker/tie/phpdocker && docker-compose up -d 1>&2"
```

and if you aren't using docker-compose you could also arrange to put an appropriate file (like @Matt's `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh`) into the virtual machine as it is being provisioned (with the `config.vm.provision "shell"`), rather than manually adding it later.

Comment: I'm not using vagrant or docker-compose. I have a plain boot2docker VM,  I need to persist environment variable even after restart. Matt's solution doesn't work after restart

Comment: hence my note about creating `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` within the Vagrantfile, to ensure that file always exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom virtual machine with proxy configuration like this

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://10.x.y.z:4951  --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.x.y.z:4951 testbox
```

It will create a virtual machine with permanent proxy configuration.

Comment: where does that information end up though? would be nice to be able to add/remove/modify post machine creation