# Docker-machine - set configuration as default

Tags: docker

Everytime I start docker-machine, I need to set a configuration like below.

```
host> docker-machine ssh default 
docker> sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

I would like to this configuration as default, so I don't need to set it no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boot2Docker allows for local customisation.](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)

Add your `sysctl` command to [`/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37703694/1318694) to have it run before docker starts.

```
echo 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh
chmod 755 /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Everytime I start docker-machine, bootsync.sh is not executed.

Comment: When you try to edit the file or when the vm starts up?  `chmod` might help

Comment: there was no 'bootsync.sh' file, so I made new one. permission error solved with sudo but seems not working.

Comment: not 'bootsync.sh', i added it on profile, and it works :)